# Registering for MouseMove: Event object is always undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Javascript object that registers for the mouse move event. But my problem is that the event parameter is not being passed in my custom function, its always undefined.

**If you look inside the function touchMove() below you will see that the parameter event is always undefined for some reason?**

What am I doing wrong?

```
MyObject.prototype.registerPointerEvents = function()  
{
  var instance = this;  // function() { instance.func(); }
  var ele      = this.getAttrib("divEle");

  ele.addEventListener("mousemove", function() { instance.touchMove(); }, false); 
}

MyObject.prototype.touchMove = function( /*Event*/ event )
{
  // Virtual function to be overridden in child classes

  console.log("MOVE 1: "+event); // here it outputs event is undefined
  if (!event)
     event = window.event;

  console.log("MOVE 2: "+event); // here event is still undefined
  if (this.getAttrib("isDragging") == "true")
  {
     console.log("MOVE TRUE");
     this.getAttrib("divEle").style.left = event.clientX+"px";
     this.getAttrib("divEle").style.top  = event.clientY+"px";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course is undefined, you are calling an anonymous function without the parameter.

Better use this:

```
ele.addEventListener("mousemove", instance.touchMove, false);
```

That is (almost) the same as

```
ele.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) { instance.touchMove(e); }, false);
```